# Hibernate Tools (hbm2java): Column Default Value is Missing

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hbm2java

I am using [hbm2java](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-tools/blob/main/maven/docs/5-minute-tutorial.md), which is part of [Hibernate Tools](https://hibernate.org/tools/), to reverse engineer a database into JPA entity classes.

I run the tool via `./mvnw clean generate-sources` and the entity classes are generated and saved to `target/generated-sources`.

In the `UserAccount` database table, the `Created` column is defined like this. Note the default value:

```
Created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
```

When hbm2java reverse engineers that column, the default value is not included:

```
...
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, length = 29)
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return this.created;
}

public void setCreated(Timestamp created) {
    this.created = created;
}
...
```

As a result, a `DataIntegrityViolationException` is thrown when trying to save a `UserAccount` entity to the database:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: not-null
> property references a null or transient value :
> com.example.UserAccount.created

Really hoping there is a way around this as I have quite a few database columns with default values, the most complex being:

```
DEFAULT 'User' + CAST(NEXT VALUE FOR SeqUserAccountUsername as VARCHAR(19))
```

...that just generates a string such as User13.

I'm still learning Spring Boot and Hibernate and could use some advice on the best approach to solving this problem.

My current research:

- The [same question](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2348736) was asked back in 2007 in the Hibernate Forums but a solution was not provided.
- [This documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/4.1.0.Final/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html) talks about using the "default-value" attribute to set the "Default initialization value for a field". Is that the correct approach?

Comment: The default value is only used when hibernate generates the tables. Thus making it irrelevant if you reverse engineer it, as the default value already exists

Answer (score 1):

I *believe* that the following mapping should work in all recent-ish versions of Hibernate:

```java
@Generated(INSERT)
@ColumnDefault("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Column(nullable = false)
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return this.created;
}
```

If that doesn't work, let me know.

(It's certainly true that the reverse engineering tool doesn't know anything about default values.)

Answer (score 1):

At first, you need to find someone who will able to clarify how that database works. The problem is SQL column definition like `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP NOT NULL` means following:

- you never select null
- you may not insert/set null
- you may insert/set not null
- you may either omit column in DML statement or specify `DEFAULT`, in that case DB generates value according to default expression (`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` in your case)

The simplest option to get **exactly the same** functionality/capabilities in `Hibernate`, is to use [JPA Callbacks](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/listeners.html), smth. like:

```java
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, /* updatable = false, */ length = 29)
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return this.created;
}

@PrePersist
protected void onPrePersist() {
     if (this.created == null) {
         this.created = Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
     }
}
```

that allows you to specify arbitrary created timestamp, and only if it is `null` `Hibernate` will use current time - that is exactly what DB allows you to do.

Other options do something similar, but **not the same**, however some of them may suit you.

1. `@CreationTimestamp`:

```java
@CreationTimestamp
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, length = 29)
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return this.created;
}
```

it ignores value of `this.created` and inserts current time, calculated on Java side, into DB.

2. `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)`

```java
@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = false, length = 29)
public Timestamp getCreated() {
    return this.created;
}
```

it ignores value of `this.created` and delegates generation of value to DB, basically it omits corresponding column in INSERT statement (well... "generate" is not correct definition here).

if you choose to use either `@CreationTimestamp` or `@Generated(GenerationTime.INSERT)` remove corresponding setter `void setCreated(Timestamp created)` in order to avoid any confusion about mutability of `created` field.